# How to perform Terminal Authentication on smart card?

Tags: nfc, digital-signature, smartcard, apdu, contactless-smartcard

I am trying to digitally sign document using the smart card eSign application. It is a national ID card, and I am following `ICAO 9303` and `TR-03110` specifications. If I am not mistaken, before selecting the `eSign` application I should perform `Terminal Authentication` as `Signature Terminal` beforehand.

In `ICAO 9303` it is stated:

```
The following sequence of commands SHALL be used with secure messaging to implement Terminal Authentication:

MSE:Set DST
PSO:Verify Certificate
MSE:Set AT
Get Challenge
External Authenticate

Steps 1 and 2 are repeated for every CV certificate to be verified (CVCA Link Certificates, DV Certificate, Terminal Certificate).
```

To Perform `MSE:Set DST` the following `APDU` should be used:

```
INS - 0x22
P1/P2 - 0x81B6
Data - 0x83 Reference of a public key, ISO 8859-1 encoded name of the public key to be set
```

It is the `Data` part I do not understand. What exactly do I need to provide there? How do I find the public key or its name?

Answer (score 2):

> What exactly do I need to provide there? How do I find the public key or its name?

Before start TA you should be sure that terminal has its own valid chain of CV-certificates + proper private key:

1. DV cetitificate
2. IS certificate of the terminal
3. private key corresponding to IS certificate

Initial step of TA is certificate chain verificattion:

1. Read EF.CVCA and find CHRs of root certificates known to chip
2. Select one that is a parent of the terminal's DV certificate. CHR from EF.CVCA must be equal to CAR from DV certificate.
3. Send MSE:Set DST with chosen CHR
4. Send PSO:Verify Certificate with terminal's DV certificate
5. Send MSE:Set DST with CHR of terminal's DV certificate (it must be equal to CAR from IS certificate)
6. Send PSO:Verify Certificate with terminal's IS certificate
   Now chip knows terminal's public key and can use it to verify a cryptogram signed by terminal with its private key.

Certificate holder reference (CHR) and certificate authourity reference (CAR) are IDs encoded as string values.

Comment: Ok, so there's probably a lot I don't understand, but I'm trying to achieve this on a national ID card using mobile phone's NFC. Should that be possible? I am also not sure I have the certificates you are mentioning, should I be able to obtain them somehow?

Comment: In every country there is special national 3-level PKI to control access to sensitive data of the chip. DV-certificate (middle-level) must be signed by Root Country Verifying CA. IS certificate (low level) must be signed by DV-certificate. If your organization is allowed to read sensitive data then it must have these certificates and private key. How to obtain depends on PKI national policy.

Comment: Well, I am doing this for my master thesis and am part of no organizations :/ There is a Europe's demo web app doing the same thing, but with card readers https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/home, and it is open source. Could I maybe somehow use their certificates? https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/code/projects/ESIG/repos/dss-demos/browse/dss-demo-webapp/src/main/resources

Comment: like he said. Sensitive data on passports and id cards are secured via Terminal Authentication. certificates for TA are not publicly available unlike ones for passive authentication. Getting test passports from a national provider without a contract seems highly unlikely. You could create your own passport but thats way to much work for a master thesis: EAC PKI for TA + ICAO PKI for BA + Chip writing (Personalization) app + ...

Comment: Regarding to your repo link: If you find cv-certificates in that app you still need a corresponding id card (personalized with those certificates)

Answer (score 0):

**JMRTD Library Can help:**

[JMRTD: An Open Source Java Implementation of Machine Readable Travel Documents](https://jmrtd.org/)

**The steps in simple words to complete the terminal authentication is like following**:

- First IS (Inspection System) send the chain of terminal certificates to the IC (Chip).
- IC verifies the chain of certificates and extracts the public key of terminal.
- IC send a challenge to terminal.
- IS sign the challenge with its private key.
- IC verify the signature.

In this way the IC authenticate the terminal and grant access to sensitive data groups.